# Reverse engineering: how do you find a differential equation from a characteristic polynomial?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After solving a differential equation, I wondered "what if I knew the characteristic polynomial, how could I figure out what differential equation I started from"?

Even though for linear systems we already know the general solution is just an exponential of a matrix, suppose you didn't have an idea at all that $y(t) = ay(t)$ had the solution $x_0 e^{at}$.

The characteristic equation would just be $ \lambda - a = 0$. If you only knew that characteristic solution, is there a way you could:

1.) Deduce the original differential equation knowing that the characteristic..... test substitution thing was $e^{ \lambda t}$?

2.) Deduce the original differential equation from a more general method without knowing what the original.....characteristic test substitution thing (still don't know what to call it) was?

Are the extrapolations to the differential equation from the characteristic equation in either case 1. or case 2. unique to at least some extent of not being completely different functions?

In order words, is it impossible some kind of non-linear system with a characteristic test of some other function like $\ln( \sin( \lambda t))$ would also yield $ \lambda - a = 0$? All you'd know more generally is that the characteristic equation given resulted by plugging in some kind of function and then differentiating it, which seems to be the same amount of information we're given by a differential equation itself.

Also, it's useful to have a broader tag than ODE because I'm not ruling out that partial differential equations might be involved in constructing a differential equation from a characteristic equation.